# Probability of choosing a central element from a set of integers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, integers

An integer is called a central element of a set of integers if at least a quarter of the elements are smaller than it and at least a quarter of the elements are larger than it. If an element is chosen randomly then what is the probability of choosing a central element?

### My thinking:

```
P(Choosing a central element) = P(quarter element will be less than it & quarter element will be larger than it)
```

=  P(quarter element will be less than it) P(quarter element will be larger than it)

= 0.25 * 0.25

= 0.0625

Is this calculation correct ? If not, where is the problem ?

Comment: No it is not correct.  Try an example.  Suppose there are $4$ integers.  How many central elements are there?  What if there are $5$ elements, or $6$?  BTW $.25\cdot.25=.0625$

Comment: ok. Then how can I get a solution?

Comment: Have you done the little examples I suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we divide the set of integers into four parts, then the elements will be either in  Q1, Q2, Q3, or Q4. The central element will be either in the Q2 or Q3 quartiles. So actually the questions asks that what is probability of selecting Q2 or Q3 from among the four quartiles?

The answer is simple. The probability is 2/4 = 0.5